# Making only one radio button selectable with PHP when not in a form

Tags: php, radio-button

I've been working on this project for school where we make a mini-lesson website that quizzes users on the a subject of our choosing. The questions, choices, and answer must all be in one array and then can be displayed as a question and radio button selection. I am up to that point and I am only working on one right now until I have completed it. My problem that I am having right now is that all the radio buttons are selectable. How could I make it so that only one radio button per question is selectable?

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
$score = 0;

    //multi-dimensional arrays for questions, selections, and answers
    $questions = array(
    array('question' => 'Which is optional to making Easy Fudge?', 
        'choice 1' => 'Nuts', 
        'choice 2' => 'Condensed Milk', 
        'choice 3' => 'semi-sweet morsels', 
        'choice 4' => 'bakers chocolate', 
        'answer' => 'nuts'),
        );

    //looping through the questions with nested loops
    foreach($questions as $question){
echo $question['question'] . '<br />';  
echo '<input type="radio" name = "nuts" value="nuts" id="nuts"> ' . $question['choice 1'] . '<br />';   
echo '<input type="radio" name = "condensed milk" value="condensed milk" id="condensed milk"> ' . $question['choice 2'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name = "semi-sweet morsels" value="semi-sweet morsels" id="semi-sweet morsels"> ' . $question['choice 3'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name = "bakers chocolate" value="bakers chocolate" id="backers chocolate"> ' . $question['choice 4'] . '<br />';  
    }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Radio buttons should share a common name, but have different values.

Answer (score 1):

Give all the related radio buttons the same name.  Example:

```
foreach($questions as $question){
    echo $question['question'] . '<br />';  
    echo '<input type="radio" name = "nuts" value="nuts" id="nuts"> ' . $question['choice 1'] . '<br />';   
    echo '<input type="radio" name = "nuts" value="condensed milk" id="condensed_milk"> ' . $question['choice 2'] . '<br />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name = "nuts" value="semi-sweet morsels" id="semi-sweet_morsels"> ' . $question['choice 3'] . '<br />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name = "nuts" value="bakers chocolate" id="backers_chocolate"> ' . $question['choice 4'] . '<br />';  
}
```

As a further note.. valid Id attributes cannot contain spaces, so in the example above, I have replaced your spaces with underscores.